# Significance test in trimodal distribution

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance

I have a trimodal null distribution that looks like this:[image]

In order to calculate the significance we just check how extreme the values are respect to our null distribution.

We do it this way:

```
  find.pvalue <- function(value, null.dist, length(null.dist))  {
    if (value<0) {
      p = (sum(null.dist < value)+1)/length(null.dist)
    } else {
      p = (sum(null.dist > value)+1)/length(null.dist)
    }
    return(p)
  }
```

Then adjust FDR.

This is how I would do it for a normal distribution, but is this correct way to test for extreme values for a null distribution like this one?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by p-value in here? It is a probability of what exactly? If you mean probability that something is greater then something else, then the shape of the distribution doesn't matter.

Comment: In this case the p-value would be the probability of finding a value higher/lower than 0.05 (whatever) in the distribution.

Comment: Then this doesn't seem to have anything to do with p-value...

Comment: It boils down to what you regard as "more extreme" (since that will then define rejection regions and p-values; it doesn't automatically mean 'further from the center' (though that may make sense for what you're doing) -- for example, one might base it directly on likelihood instead.